# How can I make my span look like an arrow using CSS pseudo elements?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Image of what I want to accomplish:

[image]

Here's the HTML fragment I'm using:

```
<section class="card button ">
    <span class="arrow">More Work</span>
</section>
```

This is my CSS. I looked at some things online and tried to play with it on jsbin but I need something that looks more like a button.

```
    .button span{
      background-color: gold;
      width: 40%;
      height: 30%;
    }
    .button span::after{
      content: "";
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 20px solid black;
        border-top: 20px solid black;
        border-bottom: 20px solid black;
    }          
    .button span::before{   
      content: "";   
        position: absolute;   
        right: -20px;   
        bottom: 0;   
        width: 0;   
        height: 0;   
        border-left: 20px solid black;   
        border-top: 20px solid black;   
        border-bottom: 20px solid black;   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this

```css
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.btn-arrow-right {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 18px;
background: red;
}
.btn-arrow-right {
    padding-left: 36px;
}
.btn-arrow-right:before,
.btn-arrow-right:after{ 
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px; 
    width: 22px; 
    height: 22px;
    background: inherit; 
    border: inherit;
    border-left-color: transparent; 
    border-bottom-color: transparent; 
    border-radius: 0px 4px 0px 0px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
}
.btn-arrow-right:before,
.btn-arrow-right:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
   
.btn-arrow-right:before
 { 
    left: -11px;
}
.btn-arrow-right:after { 
    right: -11px;
}
.btn-arrow-right:after {
    z-index: 1;
}
.btn-arrow-right:before {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-arrow-right">More Work</button>
```

Comment: Nothing is showing up except more work as plain text

Comment: check now its background color issue

Comment: Yes!! Perfect thanks.

Comment: Most welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create it with a span without CSS pseudo elements
Check this code

```
<span class="arrow left"></span>
<span class="arrow right"></span>
<span class="arrow up"></span>
<span class="arrow down"></span>

.arrow {
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
}

.right {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.left {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.up {
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.down {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

and here's the demo https://jsbin.com/tehebed/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for but this will definetely come in handy for another code challenge. Thank you.